# arity mismatch using Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm studying scheme for my degree and written this code using racket 6.10:

```
(require rsound)
(define (arpeggio n fs q) (if(eq? 0 n) (stop)
((signal-play (mysound fs))(sleep q)(stop)(arpeggio (- n 1) (+ fs 100) q))))
```

where fs is the starting frequency updated in the recursive pass, q is the time offset and n is the number of sounds played.
mysound is defined as:

```
(define mysound (network ()
        [a <= sine-wave 500]
        [out = a])
```

code works well, but at the end of the playing I get the following error:

```
; stream-time: arity mismatch;
;  the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
;   expected: 0
;   given: 3
; [,bt for context]
```

and even if I've tried ,bt for context as it says I genuinely don't get where's the error. The error accours whether the (stop) procedure is called or not in the else clause.

sample call is (arpeggio 10 500 0.1)

what's going on?

Comment: Pay close attention to your parenthesis.

Comment: And to the usage example for [network](https://docs.racket-lang.org/rsound/index.html#%28form._%28%28lib._rsound%2Fmain..rkt%29._network%29%29) that uses `signal-play`

Comment: [mcve] is missing.